# Does high level of pain alone (without fatal physical injury) necessarily lead to faint or death?

Tags: pain, death

It is known that pain can stimulate the vagus nerve which could cause faint and extreme pain can cause cardiac arrest, which could lead to death.

But is it just the pain causing the faint or death, even if the cause of pain is not fatal?
Or in other words, does this mean that all kinds of pain will necessarily lead to faint or death? Some pain may have non-fatal cause. For example, one could have very high-level pains from peripheral nerves (fingers, toes) or pudendal nerve while doesn't get injured too badly.

---

I know there are numerical ways to measure the level of pain (I hope they can make my title "high level of pain" more precise):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_scale#Numeric_rating_scale

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does intense pain cause people to lose consciousness?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/does-intense-pain-cause-people-to-lose-consciousness)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thanks! It helps. I am really surprised by that answer...